# How to make different lists for different names but add to lists if the name is repeated

Tags: python, list

I am new to coding and this is a challenge in one of my exams at school. 
This is what my text file looks like. It is storing names with different values referring to scores they got each time they did a quiz.

I am trying to make a code that produces a list for each name with three values like this:

```
ChrisNatScores = [3, 3, 3]
PiersMorganScores = [1, 1, 1]
RosylynParkerScores = [8, 8, 8]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: you should post some sample code and give it a shot yourself.  HINT: figure out how `dict` and `list` data structures work.

Comment: This dictionary has to be accessed regularly to read the data not just stored. Lots of data operations will be used

Comment: @EthanWalsh I see you edited your question again. Has it been answered or are there still things you don't get to work?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to build a dictionary rather than relying on the names of your variables.

Here's a demo, assume your file is named `testfile.txt` and has the content:

```
JoeLawrence 3
JoeLawrence 3
JoeLawrence 3
PiersMorgan 1
PiersMorgan 1
PiersMorgan 1
RosylynParker 8
RosylynParker 8
RosylynParker 8
```

Code:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> scores = defaultdict(list)
>>> with open('testfile.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         name, score = line.split()
...         scores[name].append(int(score))
... 
>>> scores
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'RosylynParker': [8, 8, 8], 'PiersMorgan': [1, 1, 1], 'JoeLawrence': [3, 3, 3]})
```

If you *really* want the variable names from your question, go ahead and issue:

```
>>> JoeLawrenceScores = scores['JoeLawrence']
>>> PiersMorganScores = scores['PiersMorgan']
>>> RosylynParkerScores = scores['RosylynParker']
>>> 
>>> JoeLawrenceScores
[3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: I would like to hear what's no useful about my answer, so that I can improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply this has helped, I was wondering, when you access that dict, why does it return the defaultdict(<type and can I still access it as a normal dictionary?

Comment: Scratch that, I just tested on it and it works so well. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @JoeLAWRENCE no problem. The defaultdict is just like a regular dictionary, but with a default value (in our case, an empty list). You can access items in the defaultdict the same way you do it for regular dicts, for example: `scores['PiersMorgan']`.